# filling PDF fields using Itext

Tags: pdf

**Source**

```
try { 
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outname)); 
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

    // fields.get("Your Company Name:", "Changed");
    // fields.get("Project Notes:", "Changed");

    fields.setField("Your Company Name:", "Changed");
    fields.setField("Project Notes:", "Blah...Blah");
    Set<String> fldNames = fields.getFields().keySet();
    for (String fldName : fldNames) {
        System.out.println( fldName + ": " + fields.getField( fldName ) );
    }     

    stamper.close();
```

**Output**

> Your Company Name: Your Name: Address Line 1: Address Line 2: City, State, Zip Code: Client's Name: Invoice ID: Client: Address Line 1: Issue Date: Client: Address Line 2: PO Number: Client: City, State, Zip Code: Due Date: Subject: Item 1: Description: Item 1: Quantity: Item 1: Unit Price: Item 1: Amount: 0 Item 2: Description: Item 2: Quantity: Item 2: Unit Price: Item 2: Amount: 0 Item 3: Description: Item 3: Quantity: Item 3: Unit Price: Item 3: Amount: 0 Item 4: Quantity: Item 4: Unit Price: Item 4: Amount: 0 Item 4: Description: Item 5: Quantity: Item 5: Unit Price: Item 5: Amount: 0 Item 5: Description: Item 6: Quantity: Item 6: Unit Price: Item 6: Amount: 0 Item 6: Description: Subtotal: 0 Discount: Amount Due: 0 Project Notes: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

I expected the `Your Company Name:` value to be "Changed" and the `Project Notes:` field value to be `"Blah...Blah"`

I have ran this code in a couple of other projects, but for some reason it's not working.

**Environment**

```
JARS - Itext 5.5.10, 5.4.1 env - Eclipcse (Kleeper) 
last modified - May 1, 2018 at 11:43:26 AM
```

I think that I have been looking at the different project versions to long. I looked the similar questions and they used setAttributes and that didn't work either. Also I ran the code with in fields. get code uncommented and received a compile error - get string undifined for type Acrofields.

Also is there a easy way to lengthen the `Your Company Name` value length when I create the new PDF file.. Currently its 21 I would like it to be about 30 char.

Answer (score 0):

You print

```
System.out.println( fldName + ": " + fields.getField( fldName ) );}
```

Thus, the output

```
Your Company Name: 
Your Name: 
[...]
```

<sub>*(at least I assume that the line breaks are there, you dropped them in your question text)*</sub>

indicates that the field names are `"Your Company Name"` and `"Your Name"` and not `"Your Company Name:"` and `"Your Name:"` etc.

Thus, you should remove the colons from your field setting calls

```
fields.setField("Your Company Name:", "Changed");
fields.setField("Project Notes:", "Blah...Blah");
```